# Creating greyscale video using Python, OpenCV, and numpy arrays

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am using 32-bit python with OpenCV 2.3.1.  I am trying to write 2-dimensional numpy arrays to a opencv video writer.  My code is similar to :

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

fourcc = cv.cv.CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')
writer = cv.cv.CreateVideoWriter("test.mpg", courcc, 10, (256,256))
if not writer:
     print "Error"
     sys.exit(1)

for ii in range(numberOfFrames):    
    numpy_image = GetFrame(ii)    #Gets a random image

    cv_image = cv.cv.CreateImage((256,256), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
    cv.cv.SetData(cv_image, numpy_image.tostring(), numpy_array.dtype.itemsize*1*256)

    cv.cv.WriteFrame(writer, cv_image)

del writer
```

I can see that I have the appropriate data in my numpy array.  And if I try reading the data back from the iplImage I see it is still there.  However, writing the frame does not appear to do anything.  No file is being made or throwing any error.  What could I be doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This snippet does not look complete. Where does `GetFrame` come from (would it be `cv.cv.GetFrame`)? What are your imports for this code?

Comment: The GetFrame is a separate function that I get the images from.  It is unrelated to the cv.cv.GetFrame().

Comment: facing a similar problem with cv2 and numpy matrices, it gives me no error, but it is writing nothing into the file!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've never used OpenCV, but FWIW I write numpy arrays to video files by piping them to mencoder (based on VokkiCoder's `VideoSink` class [here](http://vokicodder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/numpy-arrays-to-video.html)). It's very fast and seems to work pretty reliably, and it will also write RGB video.

[Here's a paste](http://pastebin.com/aaKgjsST). It also includes a `VideoSource` class for reading movie files to numpy arrays using a very similar approach.